# Converting decimal to 16 character string with or without - sign

Tags: c#, parsing, decimal

I am looking for a method that adds zero's up to 16 characters before a decimal, and a minus sign if the value is minus. E.g.,

18,52 becomes 000000000000001852, and 
-18,52 becomes-00000000000001852

I have an idea how to implement this by using replacements and if-statements, and using the [`PadLeft`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.padleft%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method where characters are padded to the left to what length you specify. But I am not sure how to make it exactly.

What I have right now is this:

```
   static string FormatDecimal(decimal d, int length = 0, char a = '0')
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        var rounded = decimal.Round(d, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
        if (rounded < 0)
        {
            sb.Append("-");
        }
        else
        {
            sb.Append("");
        }
        var lastPart = rounded.ToString().Replace(",", "").Replace(".", "");


        var lengthMiddle = length - sb.Length - lastPart.Length;

        for (int i = 0; i < lengthMiddle; i++)
        {
            sb.Append(a);
        }

        sb.Append(lastPart);

        return sb.ToString();

    }
```

When I look at the code and do `Console.WriteLine(FormatDecimal(-18m, 16, '0'))` I see that
The code is 1. very long, and 2. it does not work... The rounding fails and just keeps the -18 and no minus sign is added.

I would be very grateful if someone could help me out with this one!

Comment: Why rounding? Just multiply by 100 and pad, adding a minus if it were negative.

Comment: What's your intention with the decimal point (comma, in your example)? Do you want to replace it with a period or remove it entirely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to represent two decimal digits in your string *and* eliminate the decimal mark, you can simply multiply your number by 100. To pad up to 16 digits, use the `D` [format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
decimal d = -18.52m;
string s = ((int)(d * 100)).ToString("D16");
```

**Edit**: If you only want to pad up to 15 digits for negative numbers, you could use a conditional:

```
decimal d = -18.52m;
int i = (int)(d * 100);
string s = i.ToString(i >= 0 ? "D16" : "D15");
```

Alternatively, you could express the conditional within the format string itself using [section separators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx#SectionSeparator):

```
string s = i.ToString("0000000000000000;-000000000000000");
```

Comment: @DanPuzey: I have to look it up each time as well.

Comment: Looks shorter. :-) But what about the minus sign which has to be prepended?

Comment: @user2609980: The format string automatically takes care of the minus sign, if required.

Comment: Oh, and what if the length with a minus sign should be D15? A build in check with a if-statement if the first sign is minus?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of building this yourself, use what's already there. `decimal.ToString()` will format a number for you:

```
decimal d = 18.52;
string s = d.ToString("0000000000.##"); // = "0000000018.52"

decimal d = 18.00;
string s = d.ToString("0000000000.##"); // = "0000000018"
```

You could build your format string using the string constructor:

```
int length = 10;
string formatString = string.Concat(new string('0', length), ".##")
string s = d.ToString(formatString); // = "0000000018"
```

Note: this doesn't take care of your rounding, but I'm not clear from the question what your requirement is there.

Comment: Thanks, but the requirement is also that a -sign is prepended.

Comment: If your number is negative, the sign will be prepended.